# How to express "It's becoming too [adj]"

Tags: grammar

I'll use "cold" as an example. It appears to be that one of the ways would be to say 寒くなりすぎる, but this construction baffles me as すぎる here works in joint with なる rather than 寒い. Is it still the only correct way of doing it? Also, would it be possible to say 寒すぎてなる, and if so, how would the meaning change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*) 寒すぎてなる doesn’t work. If someone says it to me, I would ask them 寒すぎて何になる？

If you want to use an adjective, 寒くなりすぎる is the way.

The construction might start looking less baffling to you if learn to you see it as describing an excessive degree of a change (なりすぎる), rather than its result (寒い).

I will say nothing about なさすぎる for now…

Comment: 「なさすぎる」に関する情報は[な]{●}[さ]{●}[す]{●}[ぎ]{●}[る]{●}。。。とか？（＾＾）

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely other ways to say it. In Japanese, there are plenty of verbs that encompass the meaning of "become". Instead of attaching 過ぎる to adj＋なる＋すぎる, you can just attach it directly to a verb that has the same meaning.

冷める (cool down)→冷めすぎる (cool down too much)
冷える (grow cold)→冷えすぎる (grow too cold)

There's nothing wrong with using なりすぎる either.

Answer (score 0):

Phrases that comes to mind are 「寒くなってきた」 or 「冷えてきた」　but it just means "it's getting cold" so it doesn't imply extreme cold.

You can also say 「最近寒すぎる」to imply that it's too cold these days.